# what is FavoredNodeLoadBalancer and how it chooses the primary, secondary, tertiary node?

Tags: hbase

I was reading about load balancing in HBase and I encounterd with [FavoredNodeLoadBalancer](https://hbase.apache.org/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/favored/FavoredNodeLoadBalancer.html)

I have several questions:

1. how it works exactly? how it chooses primary, secondary, tertiary node addresses as hints?
2. did you have this in production? what is your experience?

thank you!